# Change in axis of the Earth if the Moon would dissappear

Tags: the-moon, gravity, earth

I read that, if the moon would not be there or if it would dissapear or be destroyed it could cause the earth to rotate into a possible axis of 45° degrees. Because it would be missing the gravitational forces of the moon that keeps te earth in the current axis of +-23.5°. If that happend a part of the earth, for example Europe, could turn in a way that it would be permanently "night".

If I understood that correctly and it is possible, would that transformation take long? Or would it be fast? And with fast I am talking about a couple of years or decades and long about thousands or millions of years.

I am working on a story that would involve this and I am trying to see if I can get the logic to work with a real scientific explanation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is  a duplicate of many currently closed questions.

Comment: Unless you make the Moon disappear by magic, the event that removes the Moon is likely to have a big gravitational impact on the Earth. The loss of axial stability would be a relatively minor thing in comparison.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft whacky close reason, can you give the author a helpful one? For example, link to a few of those so they can view the close reasons given in the questions you are thinking of?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It's important to be accurate when giving the reason for a close vote, as it provides guidance not just to the asker but also to future visitors to the page. Yes, this is a duplicate of https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29326/14094, but if that's your reason for closure then you should *flag it as a duplicate of that question*. However, that question itself was put on hold as off-topic, and I recommend this one should be closed for exactly the same reason: it's about a *hypothetical scenario*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the Help Centre says *off-topic* includes "Questions that are purely hypothetical, for example a question such as 'Could a black hole destroy the universe' or 'What if our solar system had two suns' (however, feel free to visit World Building)."

Comment: Can't be closed as a duplicate because that one does not have upvoted/marked answers.

Comment: I apologize for asking the question here because I didn't know hypotetical questions are not allowed, and I didn't know about "world building".

In my defense though the question about what happens was already asked, but my question was not what happens, my question was how long would that take for the change to happen.

Feel free to close this I will see if I can find more info on this and otherwise I will try it in World Building.

Comment: @Chappo see JanDoggen's response. I would have used that reason if I could have

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I wasn't suggesting it should have been flagged as a duplicate. I was politely suggesting that more care be taken when wording your reason for closure. Voting to close for a reason that doesn't match any off-topic criterion in the Help Centre complicates things for all of us, and undermines our credibility as community moderators.

Comment: @JanDoggen see my response to Carl. :-)

Comment: @chappo,  sorry for the brief response.  So-- when I know it's a duplicate but the dupe is closed and/or unanswered,  what would you recommend I write in the reason category for closing?

Comment: So if the question has been phrased as "What is the inclination dynamics of Earth if there was no lunar influence?" would it have been closed?

Comment: @AndersSandberg  There's a fundamental difference between "there never was a moon" and "the moon magically disappeared."